# Eclipse/PyDev: File Path Autocompletion

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

Is there any way to get autocompletion working for paths to files and folders?
I would like to create a string containing the path to a specific file or folder, let's say

```
path = '/home/username/file.txt'
```

Then I would like to be able to autocomplete this with Tab (or any other keyboard shortcut) after only typing

```
path = '/home/username/fi'
```

Until now, pressing Tab only inserts the blank space like \t would do. 
Autocompletion itself is working for variables etc.

Comment: Eclipse does not autocomplete information you enter in a string. There are so many possibilities of things you can be writing into a string so that for Eclipse to provide autocomplete, it would require an infinite amount of space

Comment: Hm, I hoped that it could work like in the IPython shell.